# USB/IP: What is the size of the iso packet descriptor?

Tags: haskell, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a virtual USB device in Haskell. So for this https://docs.kernel.org/usb/usbip_protocol.html is what looks like the specification for the protocol.

I already wrote enough code to decode all packets sent to the server (and no more) and enough code to write all packets sent to the client (and no more), at least by the formerly referenced specification. Except for the iso_packet_descriptor which size looks like never had been specified, and don't looks to be instructions for it's derivation.

So, what size should I expect?, And if it is all the rest of the size of packet how Should I implement it?

Comment: Have never worked with this protocol myself, but looks like this is a fixed 128 bit field: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/usbip/usbip_common.h#L222

Comment: @Cubic By the way any idea of where I can find with what I have to fill all the camps?

Answer (score 0):

For non-ISO endpoints, the field size is always zero.  For ISO endpoints, the field will contain an array of ISO descriptors, each 16 bytes long, with the number of descriptors in the packet given by the `number_of_packets` field of the packet.

Be warned that even though the documentation *says* that `number_of_packets` should be set to `0xFFFFFFFF` for non-ISO endpoints, the Linux USB/IP implementations doesn't do this.  Non-ISO endpoints have this value set to 0x00000000 by senders, and the value is ignored by receivers.

Nonetheless, you should be able to safely calculate the field size by inspecting `number_of_packets`.  If it's `0xFFFFFFFF` or `0`, the field is length zero.  Otherwise, it's `number_of_packets * 16`.

Note that if you are writing code for a virtual device that doesn't support ISO transfers, the field will always be length zero, and you don't need to worry about it.